# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) on 'service mysql start'

Tags: mysql

OS

```
$ uname -a
Linux aurora 4.4.0-59-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 6 17:47:47 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

MySQL

```
$ mysqladmin --version
mysqladmin  Ver 8.42 Distrib 5.7.16, for Linux on x86_64
```

Clearly something is trying to log into my mysql server as **`root`** upon

```
service mysql start
```

but I don't know what it is.

The last line in `/var/log/mysql/error.log` related to starting the server is:

```
[Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

How do I figure the offending config file or server or application that is trying to log in as `'root'@'localhost'` on startup? What other information can I provide to help to understand and resolve this issue?

Also, I am able to log in as `'root'@'localhost'` if I do so explicitly. It's only the `[Note]` in the error log that is irritating me and that I want to debug.

Comment: It could be anything, but it's probably some kind of web application you've installed.

Comment: I've shutdown `apache`. I've deleted my `crontab`. `postfix` is running but that is the only thing that I can even think of. I am open to all suggestions.

Comment: [Serverfault](http://serverfault.com) is a better place for this, as it appears to be server-related. Stack Overflow is for programming-specific problems.

Comment: I will move it. Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because the mysqladmin cannot login as root.

The guilty is this Systemd unit:

```
/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service
```

Which executes this command to see if the daemon is started properly:

```
ExecStartPost=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start post
```

Which executes:

```
# mysqladmin ping         
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'
# echo $?
0
```

The return value is 0 despite the error message so the daemon is marked as started.

Debian has a file which contains an user to execute unattended operations, to use this file explicitly the previous command must be executed in this manner:

```
mysqladmin --defaults-file=/etc/mysql/debian.cnf ping
```

After this explanation I can ignore the line in the error log.

Comment: Instead of ignoring the error I made the suggested change to the `/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start` file so the command runs correctly. Thanks